# Pass values between two html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this code where I need to pass the value of the "totalcompra" id to another page.
page1.html

```
<div id="total">
    <div class="container-total">
         <div class="text-total">
              <p>Total:$</p><p id="totalcompra" name="totalcompra"></p>
         </div>
         <div class="ahr">
              <input type="submit" id="compra_segura" class="submit btn btn-success action-button" value="Compra Segura"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to put the value here.

page2.html

```
<aside>
     <div id="side-container">
          <h2 class="quoter-text">Resumen de compra</h2>
          <div class="rsm"></div>
          <div class="pymt-total"><p class="total-pym">Total:</p></div>
     </div>
</aside>
```

ajax

```
$('#compra_segura').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/payment/',
        data: { total : $('#totalcompra').text() },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('.total-pym').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried doing it with ajax and jquery but I have not been successful.
How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: share your ajax/jquery code.

Comment: you need to read about [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [examples](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-load-method/)

Comment: Also make the button a `type="button" `

Comment: something you need to know about `ajax()` *AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. In a nutshell, it is the use of the XMLHttpRequest object to communicate with servers. It can send and receive information in various formats, including JSON, XML, HTML, and text files. AJAX’s most appealing characteristic is its "asynchronous" nature, which means it can communicate with the server, exchange data, and update the page without having to refresh the page.*  [REF.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: Use *php* to transfer data to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem):

```
$('#compra_segura').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/payment/',
        data: { total : $('#totalcompra').text() },
        success: function(data)
        {
            localStorage.setItem("totalPayment", data); //setter
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

And use `var x = localStorage.totalPayment;` to get the value on `page2.html`

Comment: Thanks, it works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, see the return of your Ajax call, if the `data` variable returns a JSON, then you must access the value of the purchase in this way:

```
$('.total-pym').append(data.totalcompra);
```

Comment: show that "data is not defined"